# Bluetooth audio on linux and soundcard?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have a relatively inexpensive desktop computer, bluetooth headphones, and the bluetooth headphones connect via a bluetooth-usb dongle.  If I purchase a hifi audio card that supports high quality audio buffering, etc, can I get the bluetooth headphones to make use of this?

Answer (score 0):

"If I purchase a hifi audio card that supports high quality audio buffering, etc, can I get the Bluetooth headphones to make use of this?". Since you have a Bluetooth headphones with an usb-bluetooth dongle. does your usb-bluetooth dongle have an aux port, if it does you can connect it to the Hifi card; via a aux cable.

Comment: No, I it's just a generic usb bluetooth stick.  Something like https://www.staples.ca/en/IOGEAR-Bluetooth-4-0-USB-Micro-Adapter/product_959028_1-CA_1_20001.  Do you have a recommendation that would be an improvement?

Comment: you'll need an [aux-bluetooth adapter](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_14?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=bluetooth+aux+adapter&sprefix=bluetooth+aux+%2Caps%2C220&crid=2QEQH6XUN0RE3&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abluetooth+aux+adapter) found this on amazon.